# Can't get my code to work in c

Tags: c

I've written a code as an assignment for my class at the university. The code is supposed to be executing newton's method to find a root for an equation (in close proximity at least) by entering the starting point and a limit. The code compiles but after i enter the necessary data the program finishes without doing anything else! Thanks for the help in advance! Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(double x)
{
    return 4 * log10(x - 1) + 3 * pow(x,2);
}
double der_f (double x)
{
    return 4 / (x - 1) + 6 * x;
}
int main()
{
    assert(f(2) == 12);
    assert(der_f(2) == 16);
    double x;
    double e;
    printf("Please give the initial estimation of the root(bigger than one) (x(0)) as well as the limit(e)\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &x, &e);
    while (x <= 1)
    {
        printf("Please give the initial estimation of the root(bigger than one)(x(0))\n");
        scanf("%lf", &x);
    }
    int n = 1;
    while (fabs(f(x)) < e)
    {
        x = x -  f(x) / der_f(x);
        n ++;
        printf("x(%d) = %lf\t", n, x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S: code runs until line 27

Comment: and we need to count upto line number 27?

Comment: What input values are you putting? Should it even enter the `while` loop with those values?

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger, and check the value of all relevant variables.  It should become clear what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not counting lines.

Comment: please [mcve] without interactive inputs. We don't want to _type_ anything.

Comment: @AntonH Also might there be a possible rounding issue using a floating type comparison for the loop condition?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Possibly, but without knowing what values OP is entering, I can't really say.

Comment: Thanks to all of you who checked it! I found the problem while checking the text of the assignment again and it is what @Eric Postpischil noted. As to the rules i'm sorry if i violate some but i'm new to question making here and i haven't really read the rules :) Guess i'll do it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fabs(f(x)) < e` should be `fabs(f(x)) > e`. You want to keep running while the value of the function is too far from zero, not while it is near zero.

Comment: I was checking the code again and i just found it, so i logged in to find if anyone has answered the question! Thanks a lot anyway!